# No encapsulation in BitmapFactory.Options

Tags: java, android, encapsulation

When studying Android's `BitmapFactory.Options` class, I noticed that its fields are publicly available to be accessed and modified.

This is contrary to the general encapsulation rule that states the fields should be declared `private`, and accessing/modifying them should be achieved via `public` getter/setter methods. This way we can control how clients can approach our class's fields.

That makes me wonder if I'm misunderstanding the encapsulation concept.
When writing my own classes, in which situations I am allowed to ignore the encapsulation, just as it is ignored in `BitmapFactory.Options`?

---

One may argue that encapsulation is not necessary when there is no need for restrictions in getting/setting the field values. But I think it is not the case with `BitmapFactory.Options`, because, e.g., [`BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) should be a power of 2:

> the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

Hence, the developers could declare a setter method that

- rejects the values that are not a power of 2; or
- rounds the given value to the nearest power of 2, before it is passed to the decoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the *Javadoc* says for `inSampleSize` is

> Also, powers of 2 are often faster/easier for the decoder to honor.

This means the `class` author is delegating to you the decision of which value to assign to it.
**Nowhere** is stated other values **won't work**, it is just they won't be **as efficient**, becuase of the rounding phase. There might be usecases where non-power-of-two numbers have to be assigned.

By giving a look at that inner `static class` I see no reason to use getters/setters encapsulation.
They would be unnecessary and redundant, like many classes which "respect" the *JavaBean* style.

Why have a 500 `NLOC` class when you can have a 50 `NLOC` one? Keep it simple.

Comment: I think other values work because they are eventually rounded to a power of 2 by the "decoder". My question is why not to do so via a setter method? Regarding the "inner static class" statement, would you please elaborate more on why such a class does not require getters/setters? While it is static, it still can be instantiated via its public constructor and have non-static fields.

Comment: @SoSa forget about the inner static thing, I was just pointing out how it is declared. The decoder class is the right place to implement the rounding logic, as here it is centralized. If the logic was inside the setter, it might have been needed to duplicate it inside each class which is used by the decoder

Comment: What I conclude from your answer is that it is not using getters/setters because there is no restrictions required in accessing/modifying the fields? And in my own classes, I should use getters/setters only when I need to implement a restriction for class clients to access/modify the fields?

Comment: @SoSa the Options class is just a simple pojo, an information carrier. Being a simple carrier it shouldn't have logic at all inside. If your class is a simple pojo which is used to carry information, you don't usually need to implement validations or some other logic type.